# search and replace string using batch commands

Tags: batch-file, search, replace

How can i search a string and replace it with a variable.
i would like to search version="1.37.0" but the version number could be anything. And there are two "version=" string in package.xml but i would like to replace second one.

how can i search version="x.x.x" and replace it with version="$variable"?
is there any one liner?

i did try to use something like this to search:

```
findstr "version="[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]" package.xml
```

and also same thing for desrciption="$variable1"

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest>
  <Package name="audio"
           description="something.  . .."
           version="1.37.0"
           comment="">
   </Package>
</PackageManifest>
```

Comment: No, no one-liner. Please supply a sample that includes your target string, else we could be guessing. What other criteria qualify the choice of the string to be replaced?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that, target string could be anything for example 1.1.1, 1.23.2, 1.23.233. search would be hardest thing but replace is just a variable which could have below example versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad hoc solution, but ...

**Edited** to adapt to comments

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Check input parameters. Needed the input file, the version and the description
    if "%~3"=="" goto :eof

    set "file=%~1"
    set "newVersion=%~2"
    set "newDescription=%~3"

    rem Read the file into memory
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do (
        set /a "line=1000+%%a*10"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%c in (!line!) do endlocal & set "l_%%c=|%%b"
    )

    rem %%a will search the required lines
    rem %%c remove blanks at the start of the line
    rem %%d get the key name

    for /f "tokens=2,* delims=_=|" %%a in (
        'set l_1 ^| findstr /i /r /c:"^[^<]*version=" /c:"description=" /c:"^[^<]*<Package"'
    ) do for /f %%c in ("%%b") do for /f "delims==" %%d in ("%%c") do (

        if /i "%%d"=="description"     ( set "value=%newDescription%" & set "newDescription="
        ) else if /i "%%d"=="version"  ( set "value=%newVersion%"     & set "newVersion="
        ) else if /i "%%d"=="<Package" ( set "packageLine=%%a"        & set "value="
        ) else set "value="

        if defined value ( setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for /f "delims=" %%z in ("!value!") do ( endlocal 
                for /f tokens^=1^,2^,^*^ delims^=^" %%e in ("%%b") do set "l_%%a=|%%e"%%z"%%g"
            )
        )
    )

    rem Include the missing values
    set /a "packageLine+=1"
    if defined newDescription set "l_%packageLine%=|           description="%newDescription%""
    set /a "packageLine+=1"
    if defined newVersion set "l_%packageLine%=|           version="%newVersion%""


    rem Output the changed information to console
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in ('set l_1') do echo(%%b

    rem Save to file
    >"%file%" (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in ('set l_1') do echo(%%b)
```

Comment: @Mihir `set "file=%~1"` , `set "version=%~2"` and then call as `doChanges.cmd "c:\somewhere\file.xml" "1.2.3.4"`. Adapt the description changes as you need

Comment: thanks again. sorry but is there is any way to save the same file after making changes..

Comment: @Mihir, uncoment the last line in the batch

Comment: @Mihir, code updated with the changes. Does it work?

Comment: how can i check for if exists? if it doesn't exists it adds to the xml file. For example "version=" does not exists in the xml file, so it adds that line with variable.

Comment: Thank you once again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@echo off

set $FindStr=Version="x.x.x"
set $ReplString=Version="y.y.y"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.xml') do (
   set $Ver=%%a
   set $Ver=!$Ver: =!
   If /i !$Ver!==%$FindStr% set $Ver=%$ReplString%
   echo !$Ver! ) >> Output.xml
```

Very simplist but a good base

**Edit :**

This will ask for the version value of the second matched `version=`

```
@echo off

set "$FindStr=Version="
set $c=1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.xml') do (
   set $Ver=%%a
   set $Ver=!$Ver: =!
   If /i "!$Ver:~0,8!"=="%$FindStr%" (
        if  !$c! GTR 1 (
             set /p "$NewVer=Enter New version : "
             set $Ver=%$FindStr%!$NewVer!)
        set /a $c+=1)
   echo !$Ver! >> Output.xml)
```

The input file is `text.xml` and the ouputFile `Output.xml`

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but "x.x.x" could be anything. it could be "1.1.1", "1.2.33". "12.22.222" it is not something which is fixed.

Comment: So how can you test it ?

Comment: huh? basically i would like a script which could search for "version="1.22.334" and version number could be anything. A user runs a script and also passes a variable which is a new version number.

Comment: Ok ! The value of Version is not important ? You just want to change it ?

Comment: yup, assuming the value of version is unknown. Sorry for confusion :)